# editing grub to boot from live iso

Tags: boot, grub2, iso, cd-image

Hey guys i am wondering if it is possible to edit grub at ubuntu 13.04 to show option to boot from live iso image on the hard drive ?, also to show option to boot to ubuntu at same time sure.